# VMware Fusion 5 with Windows 8 64 bit on MacBook Air Constant High CPU usage

Tags: macbook-pro, vmware

I have set up Windows 8 64 bit on a MacBook Air using VMWare Fusion 5 Professional.

The MacBook Air is from Oct 2012 and has an Intel Core i7 2GHz and 8 GB 1600 Mhz DDR3 RAM.

I have Windows 8 running with no other programs open but it constantly uses around 50% CPU on the Mac and the fan is running at full tilt. The VM is set up with 4GB of RAM and 2 CPU's with 2 Cores.

Is there a way to make it not overheat the Mac? Is anyone running a Windows 8 64 bit VM on a MacBook Pro or other Mac that can give me an idea if that works better?

Thanks.

Comment: Are VMWare tools installed **and** running in the VM?

Comment: Yes. The VMware tools are installed in the Windows 8 VM.

Comment: It's probably choking your resources because 1) you are doing this on a laptop which isn't designed to constantly run heavy applications like VMware and Photoshop, and 2) you allocated half of your processor cores and half of your RAM.  You gave it half your CPU, so it will use half your CPU.  Considering the MacBook Air is an SSD-based laptop, you can likely run Windows 8 just fine on a single processor core and as little as 2 GB of RAM.  However, bear in mind what the Air is and what it is primarily used for.  It's not a "powerhouse" laptop.

Comment: This question is older. I had replaced the MacBook Air with a MacBook Pro maxed out on all specs and I still saw the issue with high utilization. I think that a couple of factors are the screen resolution and probably drive encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Check the support forums on the Apple site.  I have had the same problem with 2 MacBook Airs and a new MacBook Pro Retina.  The issue is due to excessive disk writes the OSx is pushing to create the Hibernation files.  The solution (turn off the Hibernation via the Terminal app) is NOT supported by Apple but it does help quit a bit.  Until Apple fixes this in their OS, this is the only solution I have found.  I too am running Windows 8 64Bit in Fusion.  (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4029639?start=30&tstart=0) go to page 6 and 7 of the post.  Good Luck

Comment: Welcome to the site. The goal on AskDifference is to have answers stand on their own. So instead of having everybody search through the Apple Forum can you please summarize the essentials directly into your answer?

Comment: I don't see anything about disabling hibernation in that thread.

Comment: Also I don't see how hibernation is relevant. Nothing is hibernating in this scenario.